# Do slimes attack on peaceful mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was cavediving for iron (on peaceful mode, obviously), when I found a large Slime. I ran out as fast as I could. I really need to know if they attack on peaceful or not

Answer (score 5):

Though Slimes will spawn on Peaceful mode, pending some unknown bug, they will never be large enough to actually cause damage to you.

The Minecraft wiki has more information available [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Slime).

Comment: Sounds like a feature to me!